# How to display and remove text next to an element?

Tags: jquery

I want to add text next to this input tag on condition if entered value is non numeric then text comes "Please enter numeric"

Also i want to remove it if user enters Numeric

```
<input type="text" class="redBorderColor" id="Dollar" 
name="Dollar" data-require-numeric="true" value=""> <!--Add text here--> 
//Further HTMLS
```

I do not want to prefer adding some other tag. 
Is it possible without using other tag?

Comment: Add `$('#Dollar').after('Hello There!')`

Answer (score 1):

Try this : You can attach a event handle for `change` or `keyup` event or both (as shown below) and check if number is numeric or not.

On event, you can add plain text using `.after('Please Enter numeric')`, but to remove it after entering numeric value, is a difficult task. better to use some tag.

If not numeric then add `label` after `input` field else remove it.

```
$(function(){
  $('#Dollar').on('change keyup',function(){
     var val = $(this).val();
     $(this).next('label').remove();
     if(isNaN(val))
       $(this).after('<label>Please Enter numeric</label>');  
  });
});
```

Comment: He did ask how to do so without using another tag (you have placed a label). The use of the function after() is what he is looking for however.

Comment: @JonathanHolland, yeah i missed that. Let me correct my answer

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar

The above code is writing please enter numeric again and again on click of button. It should print once

Comment: But let us take use case. We have two textboxes like this. The validation entered in second textbox and message got displayed. Now i ran first textbox and enter correct value. Will not it remove the next label which was meant for second textbox? or if there is another label; will it not remove that one?

Comment: it will not remove label for second iput box and if there is already a label then add message label with some class let say `$(this).after('<label class="errorMsg">Please Enter numeric</label>');` and use same class while removing `$(this).next('label.errorMsg').remove();`